# Vue.js v-for и изменение data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Здравствуйте.
Есть такой пример:

```js
var example1 = new Vue({
  el: '#example-1',
  data: {
    items: [
      { message: 'Foo' },
      { message: 'Bar' }
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<ul id="example-1">
  <li v-for="item in items">
    {{ item.message }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Вопрос мой заключается в следующем:
Можно ли каким то образом во время перебора елементов менять св-ва каждого последующего елемента?
Тоесть если у меня будет 10 елементов 'li' - могу ли я каждому последующему например увеличивать маргин на 5 пикселей и т.п.?
(если да - как этого можно достичь.)
+
можно ли во время перебора(или как то иначе) обращаться к предыдущему елементу li и смотреть какие у него параметры?
Хотелось бы понять какой в данном случае подход является наиболее приемлемым.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исходный список при таком переборе вы изменить не можете. Но вы можете изменить вывод этого списка.

Например, вы можете использовать `index`, при обходе элементов списка.

В примере ниже, каждый следующий элемент получает `margin-top` на `5px` больше предыдущего.

На счет обращения к предыдущему элементу. При переборе списка таким образом (с помощью `v-for`) вы этого сделать не можете. Вы можете сделать это в js коде. Воспользуйтесь функцией `reduce`.

> Метод «arr.reduce(callback[, initialValue])» используется для последовательной обработки каждого элемента массива с сохранением промежуточного результата.

Подробнее про нее прочитайте [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/array-iteration#reduce-reduceright).

```js
var example1 = new Vue({
  el: '#example-1',
  data: {
    items: [
      { message: 'Foo' },
      { message: 'Bar' }
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
    <ul id="example-1">
  <li v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="item.id" :style="{ marginTop: 5 * index + 'px' }">
        {{ item.message }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: А если возникнет потребность изменить не значение маргин топ, а например какое нибудь значение дата(во время перебора) - это можно реализовать?

Comment: Тогда вам необходимо будет воспользоваться фильтрами. Подробнее о них можете прочитать в документации. https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html

Comment: Не могли бы вы привести какой нибудь самый примитивный пример связанный с фильтрами и той задачей о которой я говорил? 
В документации подобного примера не нашел..
(и доку всю перечитал несколько раз на эту тему и видео разные пересмотрел.)
Допустим если бы необходимо было, что бы значение 'Message' у каждого последующего <li> добавляло бы по 1-й букве(какой угодно.)

Comment: Точнее не так- тут я ошибся.
Моя задача не корректно поставлена в соответствии к этому коду.
В общем мне просто надо понять синтакис - каким образом фильтер может влиять на св-во даты.
(если я все правильно понял и это действительно возможно.)

Comment: Фильтры - это по сути простые функции, который влияют только на вывод информации, которая передается на вход этих функций. В самой функции вы можете написать любую логику для преобразования даты. Надеюсь, я ответил на ваш вопрос.

Comment: То что вы написали я понимаю - меня интересовал механизм передачи информации(например индекса во время работы v-for) в фильтер и как этого добиться..
То есть каким образом в фильтр может поступить индекс.
(что требуется прописать для этого?)

Comment: В документации есть пример:
v-bind:id="rawId | formatId"
Как я понимаю мы что то делаем с названием идентификатора.
Вопрос:
Как что то сделать именно со св-м даты а не с идентификатором или же обычным св-вом?
(Не знаю на сколько точно мне удалось описать проблематику.)
Или же вот так вот напрямую обратится просто нельзя?
(и надо уже химию всякую делать и комбинировать фильтры с вычисляемыми св-вами?)